# django 'tuple' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: django

this is in my views and i call it in a form. when i submit the form i get "'tuple' object has no attribute 'id'"

```
@login_required
def _login_save(request, form):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginSaveForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Create or get login.
            login1 = login.objects.get_or_create(
                                                 id=1 #this is for testing reasons to get a specific record
                                                )
            login1.name=form.cleaned_data['name']
            login1.loginUrl = form.cleaned_data['url']
            login1.password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            login1.login_username = form.cleaned_data['Login_username']
            login1.notes = form.cleaned_data['notes']
            login1.save()
    return login1
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: we should see the login model as well as your complete error :) like this, nothing is wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`get_or_create` returns a tuple in the form of `(instance, created)` where `created` is, obviously, a boolean telling you whether it found the object or had to create it. When using `get_or_create` it's best to just unpack it immediately:

```
login1, created = login.objects.get_or_create(...)
```

Then, you can use `login1` as you assumed you could.

Comment: I always forget to add `, created `.

Comment: Oh no, I just forgot to add `, created` again.